# responsive multilevel menu not working on default mobile browsers like android

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive-design

I was trying to integrate following responsive multi-level menu. Integration worked but problem is that it only works with Mobile FF and Chrome browsers on Android (Phone & Tablet)

It breaks on default android browsers

http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/

Even the authors mentions that it is not supported by all browsers. But i am sure it can be fixed.

Can someone point me to the similar free responsive menu which supports upto  3-4 levels.

I detected browser on my phone and tablet using http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ as

```
Phone: Mozilla/5.0 (linux; Android 2.3.7)

Tablet: Mozilla/5.0 (linux; Android 4.2.2)
```

Above mentioned menu breaks on both browsers when one click  on submenus. Yes it wont show submenus

I am not able to locate the source of problem why it breaks on this browser. Any expert opinion would be of great help.

Comment: Well, from what I've gathered it would appear you're looking for something fairly unique.  But it may be that all you're trying to do is nest a "collapsible" elements.  It's more of a CSS issue than a jQuery issue.
It sounds like what you're looking for could be as simple as using an "accordion" type javascript logic using <ul><li></li></ul> and nest them.

From there, it's just styling with media-queries to achieve the best look you're going for.

Comment: I would prefer to use this menu `http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/` as it looks clean unfortunately breaks in some mobile browsers. I wish it can be fixed.